# Generating pseudorandom numbers using Dual_EC_DRBG

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation, dual-ec-drbg

I am currently learning about the Dual_EC_DRBG protocol and I am stuck at the calculation of the initial state with the point P. For context, I am using the secp256k1 curve with a = 0 and b = 7. I have two points P and Q provided to me already. I am also using a nonce that will initialise the state.

From my understanding, I first take the x value of P then multiply it with the nonce value. With this new value I multiply it with the x value of Q. Afterwards I remove the first 16 digits from the value and I get the generated number. Assume all values are in hexadecimal form. However, I am unable to get the correct solution. I think there is some issues in the multiplication, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you do realize Dual_EC_DRBG was backdoored by NSA and is not reputable as a source [independent of your actual question]

Comment: and you need to provide more details probably for the question to be answered properly [first digits, etc, these need to be defined]

Comment: [Does the backdoor in Dual_EC_DRBG work like that?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51532/18298)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need the curve constants and the P and Q points. In this example I've used P-256, but it should work similarly with secp256k1.

```
p = 0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff
a = 0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc  # -3
b = 0x5ac635d8aa3a93e7b3ebbd55769886bc651d06b0cc53b0f63bce3c3e27d2604b

Px = 0x6b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296
Py = 0x4fe342e2fe1a7f9b8ee7eb4a7c0f9e162bce33576b315ececbb6406837bf51f5

Qx = 0xc97445f45cdef9f0d3e05e1e585fc297235b82b5be8ff3efca67c59852018192
Qy = 0xb28ef557ba31dfcbdd21ac46e2a91e3c304f44cb87058ada2cb815151e610046

n = 0xffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffbce6faada7179e84f3b9cac2fc632551
```

The algorithm you described in the question is close, but a little different from implementations I've seen in the wild.

1. You start with a seed.
2. You do an EC multiplication of point $P$ and the seed. The $X$ coordinate of the resulting point becomes the new seed.
3. Then you do an EC multiplication of the point $Q$ with the seed. The $X$ coordinate of this point is going to be the output of *DUAL_EC_DRBG*.
4. But before you output the data, you chop off the first 16 bits.

Assuming you already have a function that can multiply an elliptic curve point with an integer, you can generate numbers like this. In this example, *ec_point_int_mul* takes in a point $(X, Y)$ and and int $N$, and returns a new point $(X, Y)$.

```
seed = 0xd530b913e6f2ef88b21616fd34a603f203d0578c

outsize = p.bit_length() - 16  # Chop off first 16 bits
outmask = (1 << outsize) - 1

for it in range(25):
    seed, _ = ec_point_int_mul(Px, Py, seed)
    if it == 0: continue  # Do not output first iteration
    r, _ = ec_point_int_mul(Qx, Qy, seed)
    r &= outmask

    # r is the generated data.
    print(hex(r)[2:])
```

It produces output like this

```
be58a87ed729a0585d9af5e845e604c7ec2783f2b40b9dbba8cc36d9e3f0
230ce69cca1336e5d70dfca682665d0c2176d040ec693d8c6c936bf7a546
94ffaad3700ac9651c933280b9f46abf15f6b2402aec8b9c634a750add48
e206ecd890a0f00a067ad7626fd9b352561fc8a5550fccb42d80f9032fde
96c844ba91a7a8b67b5ef4b3c7920fcd62f5bd4ce0f850a2d1ff65070328
36d4f3f653b6515e3c58f51863189b92eca2bbd4321acb21ea5c448d784c
...
```

Comment: I believe the nonce I am provided with would be the seed you mentioned. Also, I think my mistake is in the EC multiplication you mentioned. I am not familiar with how proper EC multiplication is done (multiply an elliptic curve point with an integer). What I did was I took the x-coord of P/Q and multiplied it directly with the nonce.